# Changing Table Content before converting from lua to json

Tags: json, lua

Am having this problem from when I try to make information in a table as a variable.

If I write;

```
Username = "admin"                                    
Password = "admin"                                    

table = {["p_targetId"] = 0 ,["p_cmd"] = "getProductListSaved" , ["p_userName"] = Username, ["p_password"] = Password , ["p_data"] = {{}}}

Get_Info = rapidjson.encode(table)
```

I get

```
{"p_targetId":"0","p_cmd":"getProductListSaved","p_userName":"admin","p_password":"admin","p_data":[{}]}
```

which I want to get. But when I write;

```
Enter_Password = Controls.Enter_Password

Password = "admin"

table = {["p_targetId"] = 0 ,["p_cmd"] = "getProductListSaved" , ["p_userName"] = Username, ["p_password"] = Password , ["p_data"] = {{}}}
table["p_password"] = tostring(Enter_Password.String)

table2 = rapidjson.encode(table)
```

When in Textbox I write admin [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfajc.png) , I get

```
{"p_targetId":"0","p_cmd":"getProductListSaved","p_userName":"admin","p_password":"","p_data":[{}]}
```

After reading some forums. It seems my input Textbox string is not being saved into local Password, thus in table will stay as "".

Is there a way to store "admin" in Textbox into a variable, also changes when another string is in Textbox?

Comment: see `Controls.Enter_Password` result

Comment: Can you please be more specific Mike V. ?

Comment: obviously (Controls.Enter_Password.String) is an empty string. find out why. we cannot do that for you. I think Mike's comment was specific enough.

Comment: After doing some trails, I found why "p_password" is staying "". Apparently it is stay "" from when I launch the program. And whenever I update the Textbox, the variable is not being updated. Can someone tell me how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, basically needed to make a function with string.format() to save my Input in a variable.

```
if Enter_Password.String ~= "" then                         
   Password = string.format("%s", Enter_Password.String)
   table["p_password"] = Password
end
```